# Firebase Crashlytics mappingFile parameter Incompatible to AGP 4.1+

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

[image: Incompatible AGP 4.1+ to mappingFile param]

I just tried to upgrade my AGP version to v4.1+ and found that mapping file parameter now is not supported from the documentation above. How can I upload my specific mapping file in the new version ? since I still needed due to my complex android flavoring scheme and custom obfuscation location. Is there any way so I can still manage my `mappingFile` location to be uploaded by CrashlyticsUploadTask ?